# Add link to terms and conditions in Cognito Hosted UI

Tags: amazon-cognito

Is it possible to customize Cognito Hosted UI sign in web page to add a link to the terms and conditions of our web site?

Comment: Yes this would be nice

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility to do this. You can customize only layout by adding own simple CSS.